# Entity Framework Filter by grandchildren entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

If I have the following tables:

`Parent`: has `ParentId`

`Child`: has `ChildId` and `ParentId`

`Grandchild`: has `GrandchildId`, `ChildId` and `Quantity`

Whats the best approach to retrieve a list of Parents where they have a grandchild with quantity greater than 10 (for example)?

I played with linq to entity, generating something like:

```
context.Parent.Includes("Children").Include("GrandChildren").Where( ... )
```

But wasn't sure about the syntax, and I wonder about performance- do the includes load up all objects?  What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = context.Parents
                   .Where(p => p.Children.Any(
                          c => c.GrandChildren.Any(g => g.Quantity > 10));
```

`Include` will indeed load all child and grandchild entities related to loaded parents.

Answer (score 3):

The performance is bad with this approach...

```
context.Parent.Includes("Children").Include("Children.GrandChildren").Where( ... )
```

If you need the children and grandchildren at a later point or maybe don't need them at all, try to load them later with:

```
if (!parent1.ChildrenReference.IsLoaded)    
     parent1.ChildrenReference.Load();
```

Comment: This **could** perform worseif you have 100 parent records then such a technique would run a children query for each, resulting in 100 queries.  See literature on N+1 queries.